# iTunes language codes not support Vietnamese

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, locale, itunes

I have error message trying to run a simple query on iTunes store with Vietnamese language setting

Here is my url:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ok&limit=200&entity=&lang=vi_VN&country=VN

It turned out there was a problem with "lang=vi_VN" in the above query. For example, replace "lang=vi_VN&country=VN" with "lang=ja_JP&country=JP" would work fine

I have done some research online and seen iTunes do support Vietnamese (like here http://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2012/05/what-are-the-languages-iphone-supports-for-localization/)

Any idea why that link not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is `vi_VN` try with only `vi`.

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ok&limit=200&entity=&lang=vi&country=VN

Comment: thank you, its working ! May I ask where did you get that information ? That's url were generated by Xcode 9 by the way